# Unique data input to Laravel session

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-session

To create a shopping cart, I would like to add the same product only once to my Laravel session. I have tried this condition within my controller, but it's still not working. Any ideas?

**Controller**

```php
$sessions = Session::get('items.item');
foreach ($sessions as $session) {
    if ($request->name == $session['name']) {
        return;
    } else {
        Session::push('items.item', [
            'name' => $request->name,
        ]);
    }
}
```

[image: dd($sessions)]

Comment: What does `dd($sessions)` look like?

Comment: Thank you for your interest, i updated post for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will add the item immediately if the first item it finds does not have the same name. You have to check all items before adding the new one.

```
$sessions = Session::get('items.item');
    
$inItems = false;
foreach ($sessions as $session) {
    if ($request->name == $session['name']) {
        $inItems = true;
        break;
    }
}
    
if (!$inItems) {
    Session::push('items.item',[
        'name' =>  $request->name,
    ]);
}
```